# Spring security. update user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

Хочу удалить departament. Но есть ссылки в user на него. Чищу ссылки

```
public void updateUserDep(Long id){
        String sql = String.format("UPDATE `user` SET `fk_departaments_id`=null WHERE `fk_departaments_id`='%s';", id);
        getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
    }
```

Затем удаляю departament.

```
@Transactional
    public void depDelete(Departaments departaments){
        departamentsDao.remove(departaments);
    }
```

Удаляется всё хорошо, ссылки занулены у user. 
Но потом при вызове такого кода, показывает что у пользователя всё ещё есть удаленный отдел.

```
User user= (User) org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
user.getDepartaments();
```

С толкнулся с такой ситуацией первый раз. Чем можно решить такую проблему без отключения кэширования. Или всё таки лучше не удалять через sql, а доставать всех пользователей в list и очищать у user`ов отдел?

Comment: Я не вижу связи между удалением отдела у юзера в БД и объектом юзер, который хранится в SpringSecurity как Principal. Вы после удаление этот объект обновляете?

Comment: Нет, а как можно это сделать?

Comment: Самый правильный вариант, это разлогинить юзера и заставить его входить в систему заново. Можно еще так: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11769458/1646082 но это только если юзер сам у себя поменял отдел, а это по-моему уже неправильная архитектура.

Comment: Спасибо. Почитал понял что лучше руками править getPrincipal или же  чтоб выдавало null решил из  getPrincipal брать id пользователя, потом  доставать юзера из базы и уже там будет показывать null